# Start multiple h2o cluster from within R

Tags: r, windows, cmd, cluster-computing, h2o

My intention is to start two or more h2o clusters / instances **(not two or more nodes!)** from within R on the same computer/server to enable multiple user to connect with h2o at the same time. In addition, I want to be able to shutdown and restart clusters separately, also from within R.

I already know that I cannot controll multiple h2o clusters simply from within R, thus I tried to start two clusters from the command line in Windows 10:

```
java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster1 -nthreads 1  -port 54321
java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster2 -nthreads 1  -port 54323
```

This works fine for me:

```
library(h2o)

h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE, ip = "localhost", port = 54321) 
Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         4 minutes 8 seconds 
H2O cluster version:        3.8.3.2 
H2O cluster name:           testCluster 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   0.87 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    4 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  1 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54321 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
R Version:                  R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) 

h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE, ip = "localhost", port = 54323)
Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
H2O cluster uptime:         3 minutes 32 seconds 
H2O cluster version:        3.8.3.2 
H2O cluster name:           testCluster2 
H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
H2O cluster total memory:   0.87 GB 
H2O cluster total cores:    4 
H2O cluster allowed cores:  1 
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
H2O Connection port:        54323 
H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
R Version:                  R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
```

Now, I want to do the same from within R via the system() command.

```
launchH2O <-  as.character("java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1  -port 54321")
system(command = launchH2O, intern =TRUE)
```

But I get an error message:

```
[1] "Error: Unable to access jarfile h2o.jar"
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warning message:
running command 'java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1  -port 54321' had status 1
```

Trying

```
system2(command = launchH2O)
```

I get a warning message and I am not able to connect with the cluster:

```
system2(command = launchH2O)
Warning message:
running command '"java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1  -port 54321"' had status 127 

h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE, ip = "localhost", port = 54321)
Error in h2o.init(startH2O = FALSE, ip = "localhost", port = 54321) : 
Cannot connect to H2O server. Please check that H2O is running at http://localhost:54321/
```

Any ideas how to start / shutdown two or more h2o clusters from within R? 
Thank you in advance!

**Note 1:** I am only using my local Windows device for testing, I actually want to create multiple h2o clusters on a Linux server.

**Note 2:** I tried it with both R GUI (3.2.5)  and R Studio (Version 0.99.892) and I ran them as admin. The h2o.jar file is in my working directory and my Java version is (Build 1.8.0_91-b14).

**Note 3:** System information:
- h2o & h2o R package version: 3.8.3.2
- Windows 10 Home, Version 1511
- 16 RAM, Intel Core i5-6200U CPU with 2,30 GHz

Comment: Consider running linux, even as a vm guest. It generally boost productivity when working with open source. IMO win dev machine makes sense only when you deploy to that platform, i.e. azure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've changed to intern=FALSE, in below examples, based on comments

---

You should just need to change directory; it is either that or not setting wait=FALSE (to run the command in the background).

```
launchH2O <- "java -Xmx1g -jar h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1 -port 54321"
savewd <- setwd("/path/to/h2ojar/")
system(command = launchH2O, intern =FALSE wait=FALSE)
setwd(savewd)
```

The last line, and the assignment to `savewd` is just to preserve working directory. Alternatively this should also work:

```
launchH2O <- "java -Xmx1g -jar /path/to/h2ojar/h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1 -port 54321"
system(command = launchH2O, intern =FALSE, wait=FALSE)
```

When on Linux, there is another way:

```
launchH2O <- "bash -c 'nohup java -Xmx1g -jar /path/to/h2ojar/h2o.jar -name testCluster -nthreads 1 -port 54321 &'"
system(command = launchH2O, intern =FALSE)
```

(Because the last command explicitly puts it in the background, I don't think you need to set `wait=FALSE`.)

Comment: Hi Darren, thanks for the quick answer. The good news is that I can now start a cluster from within R. The bad news is that R freezes as soon as I execute  "system(command = launchH2O, intern =TRUE, wait=FALSE)". In fact, R does not freeze but it tells me that it is busy. Only after shutting down the cluster via my browser (ip:54321), R stopps being busy again...   do you have an idea?  PS: I used another path for the working directory but this obviously works fine since the cluster starts...

Comment: I got it - you have to set intern = FALSE since the interpreter waits in case you've set intern = TRUE, even if wait is set to FALSE. So system(command = launchCluster1, intern = FALSE, wait=FALSE) works. Would you mind to explain how to shutdown the clusters again via cmd?

Comment: @Constantin It should just be `h2o.shutdown()` from within R, when connected to the cluster.

Comment: By executing h2o.shutdown(), I cannot explicitly indicate which cluster I want to shutdown, right?

Comment: Your R script can only connect to one cluster at a time. So it would shutdown whichever one you are connected to (whichever one you did `h2o.init()` for).